# How to revoke edit changes wrongly done

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Hey i edited something which i was **supposed to do on an other post**. But after `submitting the same i came to realize that`. **Is there anything i can do to revoke my changes so that i dont have to bother reviewer** to check the same. They have better things to do rather than checking wrong edits.

Comment: unrelated question: why the random formatting? Is your ` key stuck?

Comment: Do you mean in this post? If yes then :P

Comment: Yes :P but I'm seriously interested in an answer. I often see code formatting abused for emphasizing but don't understand the reason. And here I don't even see the point of emphasizing this particular half sentence.

Comment: May be that part is important or has to catch an eye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On an edited post you should see near the OP name a link that says "edited... ago".
See the below image

[image].

Clicking on it, it will take you to the post revisions page where you can rollback to any version by clicking the rollback button.

[image]

Comment: Got that now. Thanks for letting me know.